# How to call function in ng-repeat after object modified?

Tags: angularjs

I have a next code part:

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-init="curMarks=getTaskVotesModalInfo(task)">
  <li ng-repeat="info in curMarks" class="list-group-item">
    <span>{{info.worker}}</span>
    <span class="badge">{{info.mark}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And all is fine. But when task updates - `getTaskVotesModalInfo()` does not recalculate data. 
task is part of `$scope.Tasks` array.

How can I fix it?

Upd: getTaskVotesModalInfo function

```
$scope.getTaskVotesModalInfo = function(task) {
   var taskId = task.id;
   var result = {};
   angular.forEach($scope.ScrumWorkers, function(value) {
       var curWorkerId = value.value;
       if (curWorkerId == 0) {
          return;
       }
       result[curWorkerId] = {
           mark : 'not voted',
           worker : 'not set'
       };
       result[curWorkerId].mark = $scope.TasksVotes[taskId][curWorkerId];
       result[curWorkerId].worker = value.text;
       return result;
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean task updates? where is the code for getTaskVotesModalInfo(task)? ng-init is probably only run once when you initialize it, and then not run again when you update?

Comment: `ngInit` is executed only once. Post `getTaskVotesModalInfo` function for better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 'ng-init' which is executed only once.

You can use the 'getTaskVotesModalInfo(task)' function directly in the ng-repeat instead of initiating curMarks in the ng-init. Then angular will handle the updates.

```
<li ng-repeat="info in getTaskVotesModalInfo(task)">
```

Here is an example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9qQcG80J0KEZ6VMXapvi)

And a more optimized example, where the 'curMarks' list is updated only after a task change: [Optimized Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/s5Jv0yr0KhlSAwOQFXIa)

Comment: While this will work - it's not recommended. This function will be evaluated each `$digest` cycle - and depending on what the function does it could slow the page down a lot. It'd be better to just run the function when you need it in the controller. Either way, this will work, just be aware of the potential performance impact.

Comment: I've added a more optimized example.